# How to cumulative sum by group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I want to know how many active students are present by month for statistics purposes.

The present data is like this dummy table:

```
start_date  quit_date   dummyName
-----------------------------------------
2015-09-12  2015-12-12  foo
2015-10-12  2015-12-12  bar
2015-10-13  2015-12-12  bob
2015-10-13  2015-12-12  rich
2015-12-13  2015-12-31  eve
```

the result would be grouped by month. 
GROUP BY and SUM does not works, it must be cumulative like this:

```
month       count
-----------------
2015-08     0    # no student added
2015-09     1    # just one student was added in this month
2015-10     4    # three more students added in october
2015-11     4    # no student added
2015-12     5    # one more student added
2016-01     0    # all students quits in december, so january there is no students
```

How can I do a query like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a handful of rows like this, you can create a table with the dates you want to report on and use correlated subqueries:

```
select date_format(eom, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       (select count(*) 
        from dummy du
        where du.start_date <= d.eom and
              du.quit_date > d.eom
       ) NumStudents
from (select date('2015-08-31') as eom union all
      select date('2015-09-30') as eom union all
      select date('2015-10-31') as eom union all
      select date('2015-11-30') as eom union all
      select date('2015-12-31') as eom union all
      select date('2016-01-31') as eom
     ) d;
```